# How can I interact with html file in delphi intraweb?

Tags: html, delphi

Hi I am currently working on delphi intraweb. I try to import html template file to the program instead of hard-code it by using components from tool palette. However, I cannot find anyway to interact with the html file satisfyingly. For example, I want to handle the values of input box in the html file or adding data to data table through delphi. Or should I perform the tasks through other aspects?

I am using IWTemplateProcessorHTML to load external html template to delphi but I couldnt figure out a way to pass values from the html file to delphi or from delphi to that html file in run-time. There is not coding involved yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For best results I recommend you showing us the code you have tried so far, and specify the part where you're having troubles.

Comment: Sorry for too general. I am using IWTemplateProcessorHTML to load external html template to delphi but I couldnt figure out a way to pass values from the html file to delphi or from delphi to that html file in run-time. There is not coding involved yet.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for (https://theroadtodelphi.com/category/javascript/)

Comment: Not exactly what Im looking for but I would study it if it could help. Thanks so much.

Comment: The search phrase *Intraweb tutorial* on Google turns up a lot of useful links that might help.